# How to enable auto complete search in Magento in frontend?

Tags: php, magento, search, autocomplete

I am using **Magento 1.9.0.1**. I have to enable `auto complete search` in `Magento`. In backend (admin area) `auto complete search` is working. But in front end this is not working. Please look the picture.

[image: b]

Like this I have to enable the `auto complete search in front end` also. How can I achieve this??

[image: f]

Is this possible without having any extension?? If no please suggest suitable extension for `auto complete search`(I already googled but prefer your suggestion). I think there is any way to `enable auto complete search`, but I don't know .

Please help me.. Any help is really appreciable ...Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento admin auto complete search is defalt magento functionality.

if u need it for frontend then u can use extesion and set it to frontend.

You can install this extension for auto complete search

**http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/search-autocomplete-search-suggest.html**

Comment: Thanks user3793635. But the extension you suggested is compatible upto magento version 1.8.1. I am using Magento 1.9.0.1

Comment: The extension is paid

Answer (score 1):

You have to use some extensions [Use This one](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/search-autocomplete-search-suggest.html) . This is for 1.8 but working fine with 1.9.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Previous 2 answers contain 1 extension that appears to be free but if you have more than 25 products you have to pay for it

Actually most magento autocomplete extension out there are PAID

here is 1 free extensions that I suggest
https://github.com/jreinke/magento-autocomplete